# deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, object given

Tags: php, laravel, haversine

When I use haversine formula to find distance, it shows me this error

> deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, object given

To get values of lat and others from mysql

```
$users_id = Auth::id();
$lon = DB::table('tbl')
        ->SELECT('lon')
        ->where("id", $users_id)
        ->get();
$lat = DB::table('tbl')
        ->SELECT('lat')
        ->where("id", $users_id)
        ->get();

$vehicle_lon=DB::table('tbl_2')
            ->select('lon')
            ->get();
$vehicle_lat=DB::table('tbl_2')
            ->select('lat')
            ->get();
```

My code

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance($lat, $lon, $vehicle_lat, $vehicle_lon, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{      

    // convert from degrees to radians
    $latFrom = deg2rad($lat);
    $lonFrom = deg2rad($lon);
    $latTo = deg2rad($vehicle_lat);
    $lonTo = deg2rad($vehicle_lon);
}
```

Comment: Where are `$lat, $lon, $vehicle_lat, $vehicle_lon` all being retrieved from?

Comment: from mysql using select query

Comment: The error message is quite clear - but the code you have shown does not show how the variables are assigned nor their values. Please add ALL relevant details or example data/variables

Comment: check my question i updated my question what else you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the below query

```
$lon = DB::table('tbl')
    ->SELECT('lon')
    ->where("id", $users_id)
    ->get();
```

you get a collection. you have to loop through it to get your desired property. you need to use `first()` to get just an object.

```
$lon = DB::table('tbl')
    ->SELECT('lon')
    ->where("id", $users_id)
    ->first();
```

But even now your problem is not solved. You get an object. You have to use it's property. So make it like

```
$lonFrom = deg2rad($lon->lon);
```

`lon` is the value you get from the database. `$lon->lon` gives you something like 0.25588484 which is required for `deg2rad()` method.

Comment: it shows me this error " Undefined property: stdClass::$vehicle_lat "

Comment: how are you using it?? use like `$latTo = deg2rad($vehicle_lat->lat)`;

Comment: your column name is `lat` not `vehicle_lat`. you have to use the column name you are selecting by the db query.

Comment: no error but i still not satisfied with result because it results me " 7096.589079796" but i want distance from all vehicles

Comment: then use get() and loop the collection to get each vehicle distance.

Comment: it works fine, what should i do if i want to get object of that vehicle along with its distance with that user, means i want to get all details of that vehicle

Comment: you mean other attributes of a vehicle from `tbl_2` in database?

Comment: just remove the `select` portion from your query. you will get all the values from db.

Comment: when i use get() mehod and use foreach loop it returns one result only i want distance of all vehicles

Comment: may be you are using a single variable for each element and thus you are getting the last element. you can add a new question with your updated code and the problem you are facing.

Comment: depends on what will you do with the values. may be you can use an array. ask a new question. remove the answer you provided. that's not an answer to your original question.